# how make the reference in order of occurance?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing a paper in LATEX, and based on the template the reference should be in order of their appearance in content. Which package should I use for it? Now this is what I'm using:

```
\bibliographystyle{iserc}{}
\bibliography{my-biblio}
```

And the template file is like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{son03}
Son, Y., Wysk, R., and Jones, A., 2003, \newblock ``Simulation Based Shop Floor     Control: Formal Model, Model Generation and Control Interface," \newblock
IIE Transactions on Design and Manufacturing, 35(1), 29-48.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Which one are you using `bibtex` or `biblatex`? Are you talking about `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`? you can take a look at  (http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.pdf)

Comment: @HarishKumar It's bibtex, but I don't have biblatex in the file type drop menu.

Answer (score 2):

This example is from [this site](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.html#styles) with a change in bibliography style.

The main file is like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\author{John Doe} \title{Sample Document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

According to the handbook of van Leunen~\cite{vanleunen},
this paragraph---and certainly this
section---should be longer than one sentence.

\section{More references}

Here we see if the reference~\cite{Narendra_1990}
to the Narendra article comes out OK, in particular,
with volume, number \& pages.

The necessary information for those who would use BibTeX
is available in the 1988 document of Prof.\ Patashnik~\cite{btxdoc}.
Interested readers who can read French may also
want to read Poussin's proof~\cite{primes}, though
it has nothing at all to do with BibTeX.

\section{Conclusion}

This is the concluding paragraph.  Here I cite another of
Oren Patashnik's books~\cite{btxhak} and, again,
van Leunen's and Poussin's~\cite{vanleunen,primes}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}   % (uses file "unsrt.bst")
\bibliography{myrefs}       % expects file "myrefs.bib"
\end{document}
```

Save this file as `mydoc.tex` (say). The reference file (.bib file) is

```
@string{jgr = "J.~Geophys.~Res."}

@MISC{primes,
   author = "Charles Louis Xavier Joseph de la Vall{\'e}e Poussin",
   note = "A strong form of the prime number theorem, 19th century",
   year = 1879
   }

@INBOOK{chicago,
   title = "The Chicago Manual of Style",
   publisher = "University of Chicago Press",
   edition = "Thirteenth",
   year = 1982,
   pages = "400--401",
   key = "Chicago"
   }

@BOOK{texbook,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title= "The {{\TeX}book}",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1984
   }

@BOOK{latexbook,
   author = "Leslie Lamport",
   title = "{\LaTeX \rm:} {A} Document Preparation System",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1986
   }

@UNPUBLISHED{btxdoc,
   author = "Oren Patashnik",
   title = "{Using BibTeX}",
   note = "Documentation for general BibTeX users",
   month = jan,
   year = 1988
   }

@UNPUBLISHED{btxhak,
   author = "Oren Patashnik",
   title = "Designing BibTeX Styles",
   note = "The part of BibTeX's documentation
                            that's not meant for general users",
   month = jan,
   year = 1988
   }

@BOOK{strunk,
   author = "Strunk, Jr., William and E. B. White",
   title = "The Elements of Style",
   publisher = "Macmillan",
   edition = "Third",
   year = 1979
   }

@book{vanleunen,
   title = "A Handbook for Scholars",
   author = "Mary-Claire van Leunen",
   publisher = "Knopf",
   year = "1979"
   }

@ARTICLE{Zurek:1993,
   AUTHOR  = {Zurek, R. W. and Martin, L. J.},
   TITLE   = {Interannual Variability of planet-encircling dust activity on {M}ars},
   YEAR    = {1993},
   JOURNAL = jgr,
   VOLUME  = {98},
   NUMBER  = {E2},
   PAGES   = {3247--3259}
}

@Article{Narendra_1990,
  author =       {K.S.Narendra and K.Parthsarathy},
  title =        {Identification and Control of Dynamical System
                  using Neural Networks},
  journal =      "IEENN",
  year =         {1990},
  volume =    {1},
  number =    {1},
  month =     {},
  pages =     {4-27},
  note =      {},
  annote =    {}
}
```

Save this file as `myrefs.bib` and put it in the same folder as `mydoc.tex`. Now you should run

1. pdflatex
2. bibtex
3. pdflatex
4. pdflatex

in this order.

For different styles have a look at [this article.](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.pdf)

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `biblatex` instead of `bibtex`.  The latter is very unflexible, and exhibits strange behavior (for example with respect to capitalization in titles).

Comment: @mbork Accepted. Some how bibtex is very rigid. But I do not have enough time now. It will be nice of you if you can get a MWE using biblatex.

Comment: The only disadvantage of `biblatex` is that the journal to which paper is communicated should accept it with `biblatex`. Otherwise only `bibtex` is the choice. One can combine `natbib` with `bibtex` and manage without trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the files. It is working with these files but when I don't get how I should chage my tex.

Comment: @HarishKumar: well, the first moment I'll have some spare time will be probably around Friday... maybe I'll try to do it then (it won't be very easy since I have no experience with biblatex except for reading the manual; I use amsrefs instead, and AFAIK it does not have such functionality).

Comment: @anna: Based on the sample code you've provided I think you just need to replace `\bibliographystyle{iserc}{}` with `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` - although I may have misunderstood the question...